# What are the 6th and 7th (decimal val 32 and 64) for in PipeAccessRights, and should I remove them?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a C# program that instantiates a NamedPipeServerStream. I want to make sure that the access rights are locked down so that only the current user can use it. I noticed that there are some groups granted access by default, two of which are LocalSystem and Administrators. When attempting to remove these rights, I noticed that they have PipeAccessRights.FullControl as well as the 6th and 7th bit (decimal equivalent of 32 and 64). Those bits are not listed in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipeaccessrights?view=netframework-4.8

What are those bits for, and can I remove them safely?

I have successfully been able to remove them by casting an integer (2032127) to the PipeAccessRights enum.

Here is what I am currently doing to instantiate the pipe and remove rights of all users/groups except the current user:

```cs
var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(this.pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 5, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

var ps = pipeServer.GetAccessControl();

ps.RemoveAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.Read | PipeAccessRights.Synchronize, AccessControlType.Allow));
ps.RemoveAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AnonymousSid, null), PipeAccessRights.Read | PipeAccessRights.Synchronize, AccessControlType.Allow));
ps.RemoveAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null), (PipeAccessRights)2032127, AccessControlType.Allow));
ps.RemoveAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null), (PipeAccessRights)2032127, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-mask

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the link. Would you mind clarifying how that applies to the PipeAccessRule? I see a 31st bit, but that is for GENERIC_READ, which is already specified elsewhere in PipeAccessRights.

Comment: I have no idea how you could see a 64th bit in a 32-bit enum type.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, 6th and 7th bit (equal to 32 and 64 in decimal). I've updated the post.

Comment: Do note that explicitly removing rights for administrators (and local system) is largely a symbolic exercise. An administrator can always do anything, including changing the ACL of a pipe back to include administrators, or just injecting code in the process controlling the pipe. It's true that doing so requires a bunch of programming that's not likely to be undertaken by your average administrator, but even so removing these rights is no more than a speed bump.

Comment: Its not so cleanly separated, access rights for pipe, file and directory objects are intermingled.  0x0020 is FILE_EXECUTE access for a file and FILE_TRAVERSE access for a directory.  0x0040 is FILE_DELETE_CHILD access for a directory.  I have no theory for what they could mean for a pipe object, or how they got turned on in the first place, turning them off should not have any side-effects.

Comment: Also, rather than selectively removing rules (which is quite error prone) it makes more sense to create a specific ACL to grant the current user control and nothing else, and use `SetAccessControl` to replace the old one entirely. As a side effect, this even requires less code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, that answers my question as to what those bits are for. I assume they are probably just set by default, but not applicable to pipes. Do you have a link to documentation for those values? I did not see it in the first link you sent

Comment: I just looked in the SDK file that defines these flags, winnt.h.  FILE_DELETE_CHILD googles well, take the first hit.

Answer (score 1):

As @HansPassant said in a comment on my question, the 6th bit (0x0020) is FILE_EXECUTE access for a file and FILE_TRAVERSE access for a directory, and the 7th bit (0x0040) is FILE_DELETE_CHILD access for a directory. I am assuming these bits are set to true by default for administrators, but are not actually applicable to pipes.

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-access-rights-constants

As for whether to remove these rights, @JeroenMostert mentions that it will likely have no effect, as Administrators can override the permissions. Additionally, a more logical solution would be to completely replace the Pipe Access Rights with the Rights that I need, namely, solely read/write access for the current user.

Comment: They can't override them.  Some odds they can login with that user account.